# kettle etl sum values from Output steps metrics

Tags: kettle

Background: I am on PDI 6 and I am new.

I have this transformation:

[image]

The top 3 steps just read some data from a database (postgresql) and write to a text file. I need to also generate another file to record some info of this operation, the info will be number of rows extracted, start time of the extraction, end time of the extraction, there are more but are static texts. So I found Output steps metrics, which seems to be able to help.

So in the bottom line of steps, first step is Output steps metrics, there is a image of previewing the step. As you see, there is a duration for each step involved in the extraction. I want to sum the durations and use current date time minus the sum to get the start time of the extraction. I think to do that in the step Modified Java Script value 2 but not sure how. The rest of steps in the bottom just do simple stuff like adding static fields and finally output the result in Text file output 2.

BTW, is this the correct way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Javascript to calculate the sum of durations and then doing the maths with the current date, you can make use of **Get System Info** step in PDI. Select the type as : `system date (variable)`. give some name to this type *(e.g. start_datetime)*. Now once you execute the transformation, you will get rows of steps metrics along with their `start_datetime`. Take the minimum of this to get the starting time of your execution. You can easily achieve this by the `Group By` step in PDI.

You transformation will look as below:

[image]

Hope this helps :)